# How to cancel PendingIntent at specific time?

Tags: java, android, service, alarmmanager, android-pendingintent

AlarmManager works perfectly when I have not declared `cancel` but do not fire when I declare the `cancel`..
Here is the code:

```
Calendar c= Calendar.getInstance();
                c.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0); 
                c.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 37);
                c.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

            Toast.makeText(this, c.getTime().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        intent = new Intent(TestAlarm.this, TestAlarmService.class);
        pi = PendingIntent.getService(TestAlarm.this, 1, intent, 0);
        AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, c.getTimeInMillis(), pi);
```

and `cancel` code:

```
 c.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
        c.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 38);
        c.add(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        PendingIntent pi1=PendingIntent.getService(TestAlarm.this, 1, intent, 0);
        AlarmManager am1 = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        //stopService(intent);
        am1.cancel(pi);
```

Now here I want to start my `AlarmManager` to go off at 12:37 and `cancel` after one or two minutes...But Whenever I use `cancel` code the `AlarmManager` never fires...
Thanks in Advance! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the line `am1.cancel(pi);` to `am1.cancel(pi1);` - you're cancelling the original `PendingIntent`

Also, in your cancel code, you're calling `c.add()` (which add on to the current date/time) instead of `c.set()` (which explicitly sets the next date/time). By calling `c.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 38)`, you're actually adding 38 minutes to the current Calendar, instead of setting the time to 12:38;

Comment: Thanks @WATTO but the Service called with it is not stopped! And please tell me how can I know if the PendingIntent is cancelled?

Comment: You are using `c.add()` instead of `c.set()` in your cancel code. This means its adding 38 minutes to the current time, instead of setting the current time to "12:38". See my edited answer.

Comment: Thanks @WATTO for correcting me...:) But now if I am using `setRepeating` it is only fired when I am clicking the button...WEll my problem is solved. Thanks!